# How can I convert ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<Object> using .collect(Collectors.toList() in Java stream

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

How can I convert `ArrayList<String>` to `ArrayList<Object>` using `.collect(Collectors.toList()` in Java stream

Earlier I used

```
CommonList = detailUtils.SelectIDValueGetterObservable(getActivity()).stream()
                .forEach(i -> CommonList.add(new foo(i));`
```

However I came across these **Side-effects**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Which suggest to `.collect(Collectors.toList()`

how can we do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier than you might believe. Just invoke `addAll`.

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
strList.add("hello");
strList.add("world");

List<Object> genericList =new ArrayList<>();
genericList.addAll(strList);
System.out.println(genericList);  //--> [hello,world]
```

Beware, as this could also be dangerous...

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
intList.add(1);
intList.add(2);
genericList.addAll(intList); //yeah, ok

boolean[] boolArray = new boolean[5];
genericList.add(boolArray);    //why not
genericList.add(false);        //no worries, it will cast it to Boolean
genericList.add(genericList);  //so inclusive!

System.out.println(genericList);   
//diversity badge achieved!-> [hello,world,1,2,[Z@232204a1,false,(this Collection)]
```

Answer (score 2):

if u wanna use lambda, u can use [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method.

like this

```java
Stream.of("A", "B").map(e -> (Object) e).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can’t “convert” it (ie change its type), but you can just:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>(myStringList);
```